# SQL join multiple tables with/without data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, exists, outer-join

I have no idea how to create an SQL statement to join 4 tables.
1) The 'Vendor Table will always match entries from each table on Vendor #
2) Each of the remaining 3 will match to each other by Vendor # & Seq #
3) Any combination of the 3 can have data (or not)
4) I don't want to select from the Vendor table unless I get a hit on at least one of the 3

VENDOR

```
Vendor #      Name   
--------      ----  
   1        Tom Smith   
   2        Bruce Lee   
   3        Seamus O’Leary   
   4        Jonathan Stewart   
   5        Benjamin Franklin
```

Month Range Selected

```
Vendor #   Seq #   MonthFrom   MonthTo
--------   -----   ---------   -------
    1        1         3          6
    1        2         7          9
    3        2         5          6
```

Week Selected

```
Vendor #    Seq #     Week #
--------    -----     ------
    1         1         3
    3         1         4
    4         1         1
```

Day Selected

```
Vendor #    Seq #    Day #
   1          1        15
   1          2        25
   2          1        12
   4          1        05
   5          1        19
```

Desired Table (Joined)

```
Vendor#   Name          Seq#   MonthFrom   MonthTo   Week#   Day#
   1    Tom Smith         1        3          6        3      15
   1    Tom Smith         2        7          9      NULL     25
   2    Bruce Lee         1       NULL       NULL    NULL     12
   3    Seamus O’Leary    1       NULL       NULL      4     NULL
   3    Seamus O’Leary    2        5          6      NULL    NULL
   4    Jonathan Stewart  1       NULL       NULL      1      05
   5    Benjamin Franklin 1       NULL       NULL    NULL     19
```

The trick being that any of the 3 (not including 'Vendor') can or cannot have data and I only want a row returned if there is something from one or more of the 3.

Any Advice?

Comment: What DBMS? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server...?

Comment: I'm sorry - SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

To join it on Vendor and Seq, we first need to have all possible combinations. Then we can filter the tables based on these combinations. I've ran the following in SQL server:

**Setup**

```
declare @Vendors table(id int, name varchar(20));
declare @MonthRangeSelected table (vendor int, seq int null, monthFrom int null, monthTo int null);
declare @WeekSelected table (vendor int, seq int null, week int null);
declare @DaySelected table (vendor int, seq int null, day int null);

insert into @Vendors
select 1, 'Tom Smith'
union all
select 2, 'Bruce Lee'
union all
select 3, 'Seamus O’Leary'
union all
select 4, 'Jonathan Stewart'
union all
select 5, 'Benjamin Franklin';

insert into @MonthRangeSelected
select 1, 1, 3, 6
union all
select 1, 2, 7, 9
union all
select 3, 2, 5, 6;

insert into @WeekSelected
select 1, 1, 3
union all
select 3, 1, 4
union all
select 4, 1, 1;

insert into @DaySelected
select 1, 1, 15
union all
select 1, 2, 25
union all
select 2, 1, 12
union all
select 4, 1, 05
union all
select 5, 1, 19;
```

**Query**

```
   select v.Id, v.name, combinations.seq, MonthFrom, MonthTo, Week, Day
     from @Vendors v
inner join (select m.vendor, m.seq
              from @MonthRangeSelected m
             union
            select w.vendor, w.seq
              from @WeekSelected w
             union
            select d.vendor, d.seq
              from @DaySelected d) combinations
       on combinations.vendor = v.id
left join @MonthRangeSelected m
       on m.Vendor = combinations.vendor
      and m.seq = combinations.seq
left join @WeekSelected w
       on w.Vendor = combinations.vendor
      and w.seq = combinations.seq
left join @DaySelected d
       on d.Vendor = combinations.vendor
      and d.seq = combinations.seq
    where (MonthFrom is not null
       or MonthTo is not null
       or Week is not null
       or Day is not null)
```

And this is the result:

```
Id    name              seq    MonthFrom    MonthTo    Week    Day
1     Tom Smith         1      3            6          3       15
1     Tom Smith         2      7            9          NULL    25
2     Bruce Lee         1      NULL         NULL       NULL    12
3     Seamus O’Leary    1      NULL         NULL       4       NULL
3     Seamus O’Leary    2      5            6          NULL    NULL
4     Jonathan Stewart  1      NULL         NULL       1       5
5     Benjamin Franklin 1      NULL         NULL       NULL    19
```

Comment: I don't think that this properly accounts for the Seq# values matching between the three lookup tables.

Comment: But will this join the 3 on sequence #? (Tom H beat me to it)

Comment: @DimitriHotchingurtis No, it didn't. I have corrected the query and tried it in SQL server and the results seem to match.

Comment: This (along with Tom H) got me just what I needed - much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is more complicated than it sounds.  According to the result, you do not want a cartesian product when there are multiple matches in a table.  So, you need to take seqnum into account.

```
select v.Vendor, v.name, coalesce(m.seq, w.seq, d.seq) as Seq,
       m.MonthFrom, m.MonthTo, w.Week, d.Day
from Vendors v left join
     SMonthRangeSelected m
     on v.Vendor = m.Vendor full join
     WeekSelected w
     on v.Vendor = w.Vendor and m.seq = w.seq full join
     DaySelected d
     on v.Vendor = d.Vendor and d.seq in (w.seq, m.seq)
where m.Vendor is not null or
      w.Vendor is not null or
      d.Vendor is not null;
```

Strange things can happen when using `full join`, particularly if you want any filtering.  An alternative approach uses `union all` and `group by`:

```
select mwd.Vendor, v.name, mwd.seq,
       max(MonthFrom) as MonthFrom, max(MonthTo) as monthTo,
       max(Week) as week, max(Day) as day
from ((select m.Vendor, m.seq, m.MonthFrom, m.MonthTo, NULL as week, NULL as day
       from month m
      ) union all
      (select w.Vendor, w.seq, NULL as MonthFrom, NULL as MonthTo, w.week, NULL as day
       from week
      ) union all
      (select d.Vendor, d.seq, NULL as MonthFrom, NULL as MonthTo, NULL as week, d.day
       from day d
      )
     ) mwd join
     Vendor v
     on v.vendor = vmwd.vendor
group by mwd.Vendor, v.vname, mwd.seq;
```

Note that this version does not require the `Vendor` table.

Comment: Since Vendor Name is only in the Vendor table, you still need to join back to it at the outermost level.

Answer (score 0):

You should left outer join to each of the 3 tables, and then include the following in your where clause:

```
(MonthFrom is not null or Week# is not null or Day# is not null)
```

it sounds like you can inner join to the Vendor table

Answer (score 0):

You need full outer joins on the three tables, so as to get all vendor and seq number combinations. Join these with vendor and you are done:

```
select vendorno, v.name, x.seqno, x.monthfrom, x.monthto, x.weekno, x.dayno
from vendor v
join
(
  select vendorno, seqno, m.monthfrom, m.monthto, w.weekno, d.dayno
  from monthsel m
  full outer join weeksel w using (vendorno, seqno)
  full outer join daysel d using (vendorno, seqno)
) x using(vendorno)
order by vendorno, x.seqno;
```

**UPDATE:** Without a USING clause the same query get slightly less readable (and thus slightly more error-prone):

```
select v.vendorno, v.name, x.seqno, x.monthfrom, x.monthto, x.weekno, x.dayno
from vendor v
join
(
  select 
    coalesce(m.vendorno, w.vendorno, d.vendorno) as vendorno,
    coalesce(m.seqno, w.seqno, d.seqno) as seqno,
    m.monthfrom, m.monthto, w.weekno, d.dayno
  from monthsel m
  full outer join weeksel w on w.vendorno = m.vendorno and w.seqno = m.seqno
  full outer join daysel d on  d.vendorno in (m.vendorno, w.vendorno)
                           and d.seqno in (m.seqno, w.segno)
) x on x.vendorno = v.vendorno
order by v.vendorno, x.seqno;
```

(Hope I didn't mix things up here. It's easy to make copy & paste errors with such a query. So if it doesn't work properly, look out for typos.)

Comment: Does SQL Server support the `using` clause?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Oh, doesn't it? I don't know. Multiple full outer joins are quite horrible without it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will do what you need:

```
SELECT
    V.[Vendor#],  -- I'll never understand why people insist on using names that require brackets
    V.Name,
    COALESCE(M.[Seq#], W.[Seq#], D.[Seq#]) AS [Seq#],
    M.MonthFrom,
    M.MonthTo,
    W.[Week#],
    D.[Day#]
FROM
    Vendor V
LEFT OUTER JOIN MonthRange M ON M.[Vendor#] = V.[Vendor#]
LEFT OUTER JOIN Week W ON W.[Vendor#] = V.[Vendor#]
LEFT OUTER JOIN Day D ON D.[Vendor#] = V.[Vendor#]
WHERE
    (
        M.[Vendor#] IS NOT NULL OR
        W.[Vendor#] IS NOT NULL OR
        D.[Vendor#] IS NOT NULL
    ) AND
    (M.[Seq#] = W.[Seq#] OR M.[Seq#] IS NULL OR W.[Seq#] IS NULL) AND
    (M.[Seq#] = D.[Seq#] OR M.[Seq#] IS NULL OR D.[Seq#] IS NULL) AND
    (D.[Seq#] = W.[Seq#] OR D.[Seq#] IS NULL OR W.[Seq#] IS NULL)
```

Comment: this is getting me close!